# How do I give a UITextView focus programmatically?

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uikit

So I want to bring in a modal view controller that has a UITextView in it and I want the keyboard to automatically popup and the UITextView have focus.

I found a way to accomplish this by doing the following:

```
textView.editable = YES;
textView.editable = NO;
```

This just seems hacky to me, is there another way?

Answer (score 168, accepted):

Since `UITextView` inherits from `UIResponder` (indirectly, it actually inherits from `UIScrollView`, which inherits from `UIView` which *then* inherits from `UIResponder`) you can call the `-becomeFirstResponder` method on your text field, which will cause it to become the first responder and begin editing:

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 32):

Swift:

```
textView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 12):

That does seem somewhat hackish.

The Cocoa Touch terminology for 'having focus' is 'first responder' and `UITextView`s will display their keyboards when they are the first responder.  I can think of several techniques to make the UITextView become the first responder, but the easiest is probably in your view controller's viewWillAppear or viewDidAppear methods:

```
- (void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{

    [myTextView becomeFirstResponder];

    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}
```

Answer (score 7):

```
[textView becomeFirstResponder];
```

Answer (score 1):

When you want the focus to be that particular TextView on loading a ViewController, you can place the textView.becomeFirstResponder() in the ViewDidLoad overrode func as below:

```
 override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

textView.becomeFirstResponder()

}
```

I find this works without any errors

Answer (score -1):

On Xamarin Forms Custom Render:

```
   protected override void OnElementChanged(ElementChangedEventArgs<Entry> e)
    {
        base.OnElementChanged(e);

        if (Control != null)
        {
            Control.BecomeFirstResponder();
        }
    }
```