# TextView selected when entering a view in iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode

I have a ViewController specifically for making a comment, it opens when "Comment" button is pressed in MainVC and only contains a UITextView.

User has to click on the UITextView for the keyboard to appear to start typing.

Is it possible to make the UITextView selected by default when entering the view?

Comment: just search, google you have plenty of questions about that http://stackoverflow.com/questions/987975/how-do-i-give-a-uitextview-focus-programmatically

Answer (score 0):

This should do the trick (put it inside e.g. viewDidLoad())

```
yourTextView.becomeFirstResponder()
```

Answer (score 0):

In you **viewWillAppear** method of comment viewController

```
override func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
    super.viewWillAppear(animated) 
    textview.becomeFirstResponder()
}
```

so whenever your **viewController will be appearing** the **keyboard** will **appear** as **textview becomes active responder**.

Answer (score 0):

There is an one method **becomeFirstResponder()** that will help you to focus in UIKit like textField.

Put this method in **viewDidAppear()** or **viewDidLoad()**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        txtcheck.becomeFirstResponder()

    }
    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
        super.viewDidAppear(animated)
        txtcheck.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
```